# z-index not working to get an element above the overlay

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a horizontal list boxes which is overlapped by a pop up overlay. And horizontal boxes are structured using `ui li`

Now the question is, how to get the single box above the overlay using `z-index`. In my example I need to get the `li` which has class name `.test` above the overlay div.

```css
.wrapper { position: relative }

ul li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

li {
  background:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  width:60px;
  height: 60px;

}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:10
}

.test {
  z-index:100 /*not working */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rocelive/3/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property works on positioned elements. You could add `position: relative;` to the element to get the `z-index` property to work:

```
.test {
  z-index:100;
  position: relative;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rocelive/4/edit)**

Comment: oops I had tried this but didnt work.. Let me check is there any other z-index values used in my code

Comment: This solution is not working for me, even though I have applied position relative and higher z-index to the element which needs to stand out.

Comment: @darKnight There might be another [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) that causes the trouble. The order of stacking contexts matters. Elements in a higher stacking context overlay the others.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `position: relative;` to your test class